# How to show taxonomy image instead of taxonomy name on a list

Tags: taxonomy

I would like to show in a custom taxomony list icons instead of taxonomy name , but just for the ones with image asociated, where there is no image let show the taxonomy name .

i have  installed taxonomy-images plugin also , 
but it only adds the images ,  does not replace the  taxonomy name.
tnx

this is the code i have in the archive{custom type}.php file

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'custom_type','posts_per_page' => 20 ) ); ?>

                        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                        <div class="col-md-3 clearfix"><div class="row"><article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'clearfix' ); ?> role="article">

                             <?php // end article header ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                            <section class="entry-content" style="text-align:center;padding:20px;">
                            <div class="thumcap2"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
  the_post_thumbnail(thumbnail);
} 
?></a><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="title2" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>


                            </section> <?php // end article section ?>

                            <footer class="article-footer" style="text-align:center;">
<?php
                                    printf( __( ' %4$s', 'bonestheme' ), get_the_time( 'Y-m-j' ), get_the_time( __( 'F jS, Y', 'bonestheme' )), bones_get_the_author_posts_link(), get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'custom_cat', ' ', ' | ', '' ) );
                                ?>
                            </footer> <?php // end article footer ?>

                        </article></div></div> <?php // end article ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?><div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: First of all, [don't use `query_posts`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts). Second, it's unclear what you've tried yourself so far and what went wrong. Please elaborate.

Comment: Just to add, `showposts` has been depreciated a long time ago. You should be using `posts_per_page`

Comment: Well , i suppose that  better is if you have a look  at the live website ,  www.hh-escorts.de

Comment: Well , access the live website ,hh-escorts.de ,if you click on the menu tab All Models ,  you will call a template all-models.php where the above code is contained ,under each model thumbnail , as u can see are shown the model categories (wich are in fact custom post type taxonomies "custom_cat")  the point is that if i have as taxonimies ,  the city , and some other like Blonde, travel, bisex  etc ,  the visualization will be to big , and it will deform the grid view , so  for all other that are not the cities i want to add an icon instead of the taxonomy name

Comment: p.s. : and if i dont use the query , the template will not understand wich post_type  archive it has to show

Comment: Use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to construct your custom loop, not `query_posts`

Comment: ok ,  i can  do that , is not this the point , my question is another , please read and if poosible  give me a hint .

Answer (score 0):

i managed to fix it
without plugin ,  just saved in the theme image path pict with taxonomz slug name .png  and this code modification

```
<footer class="article-footer" style="text-align:center;">
 <?php  //$terms= apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-list-the-terms', '', array('taxonomy'     => 'custom_cat',)); ?>
<?php //print_r( $terms); ?>
<?php  $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom_cat' ); 
$numcat=sizeof($terms);
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {


 $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'custom_cat' );
 if( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH .'/images/'. $term->slug .'.png') ){
?>
    <a rel="tag" href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><img title="<?php  echo $term->name; ?>" style="height: 21px; width: 21px;" src="<?php echo  get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/' . $term->slug . '.png' ?>" alt="<?php  echo $term->name; ?>"></a>| 
<?php }else{ ?>
 <a rel="tag" href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><?php  echo $term->name; ?></a>| 
 <?php } }

                                    //printf( __( ' %4$s', 'bonestheme' ), get_the_time( 'Y-m-j' ), get_the_time( __( 'F jS, Y', 'bonestheme' )), bones_get_the_author_posts_link(), get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'custom_cat', ' ', ' | ', '' ) );
                                ?>
                            </footer> <?php // end article footer ?>
```